# How to cancel installation from Ubuntu Software (NOT Center)?

Tags: package-management, software-center

I installed 0 A.D. with Ubuntu Software this morning, got the notification that it had installed, I played it, etc., and now I'm trying to install PulseEffects. It wouldn't install and I couldn't figure it out until I opened Ubuntu Software and saw ***it*** says that 0 A.D. is still installing even though it's not. Is there a killall command or something that I can use to stop it?

It's *not* Ubuntu Software **Center** I'm using, it's just Ubuntu Software.

The output of `pgrep apt` is:

```
20699 21832
```

The output of `pgrep apt -a` is

```
20699 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
21832 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
```

Comment: what is the output of `pgrep apt` ?

Comment: @ Ravexina `20699
21832`

Comment: `pgrep apt -a`?

Comment: @Ravexina `20699 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd



21832 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd`

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: @Ravexina It would not update because another process is using it. I did what Samar said to do and ended the gnome-software process that was running and that fixed it.

Comment: If you encounter the same issue again, let me know we can diagnose it to find out what is causing the problem ... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened system monitor, searched `software` and the only process was `gnome-software` and I ended the process. That fixed the issue.